# how to get the row data in data table

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am in a situation, I am trying to get the specific row's data from data table. I am new to dataTable.

so here is the situation,
bellow is my data table content show in the picture.
[image: data table]

bellow is the code for my Data Table

```html
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table =$('#example').dataTable({
     
     "processing": true,
     "ajax": {
        "url":'/myWeb/Controller/getUserList',
        "dataSrc":""
          },        
     "columns": [
                 { "data": "userName"},
        { "data": "roles" },
       
       
       
               {
                   data:   "userName",
                   render: function ( data, type, row ) { 
                   
                       if ( type === 'display' ) {
                           return '<button type="button" id='+data+' class="btn btn-default btn-sm"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUser" data-whatever="@getbootstrap()" onclick="getUserName(this.id)" > <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit </button>';                          
                       }
                       //alert(data);
                       return data;
                   }
               },
               {
                data : "userName",
                       if ( type === 'display' ) {
                           return '<button type="button" id='+data+' class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="countUserRecord(this.id)"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete </button>';                          
                       }
                       //alert(data);
                       return data;
                   }
               }
                           
              ],
    "paging":   false,
    "info":     false,
    "filter":   false,
    "sort":  false
    
    });
} );
```

On the delete button as I am passing userName,I want pass role also, 
so i tried this

```html
role = row.roles;
userName = row.userName;
status = row.status;
alert("username :"+userName+" role: "+role);
```

but When I do this I am getting different role for each user. It is giving me wrong user's role.

bellow is my Json structure Which I am getting from DB.

```js
[
{"userName":"admin",
"password":null,
"roles":"Admin",
"status":"Active",
"email":"emailAdmin"},

{"userName":"varun",
"password":null,
"roles":"User",
"status":"Active",
"email":"emailVarun"},

{"userName":"bob",
"password":null,
"roles":"Admin",
"status":"Active",
"email":"undefined"}
]
```

What I want to do is When I click on delete user button , it should pass userName and role also, how do I do this,

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$('table').on('click','.addDeleteClassToDeleteBtns',function(){
     var containerRow = $(this).parents('tr');
     var userName    = containerRow.find('td:first-child').html();
     var role         = containerRow.find('td:nth-child(2)').html();
     alert(role+' '+userName);
});
```

or

```
function countUserRecord(deleteId){
     var containerRow = $('#deleteId').parents('tr');
     var userName    = containerRow.find('td:first-child').html();
     var role         = containerRow.find('td:nth-child(2)').html();
     alert(role+' '+userName);
}
```

You could edit the selectors to better suit your code.